# Mute multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

My iPhone app has roughly about 15 views, on each view I have a different audio file playing through AVAudioPlayer. I want to add a mute/unmute button on each page so that whenever user mutes the app on a particular page, it remains mute throughout the application unless user decides to unmute.

When I did set audioPlayer.volume=0.0;  on a view, it should not automatically unmute in the next view, whereas it does. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use a **singleton class** something like MyAudioPlayer, and from each page you can ask MyAudioPlayer singleton object to play a given audio file. setting the singleton player mute, will remain mute throughout the application

or

Declare the AVAudioPlayer object in AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. I was actually thinking of using NSUserDefaults, but this should work too.

Comment: I tried the app delegate method, wherein I declared AVAudioPlayer object as well as methods for playback/volume(on,off) in AppDelegate, and added objects of AppDelegate in each view controller, however this is not working and volume still resets to 1.0.

Comment: after much thought, I figured that volume is being reset because each time the audio file changes, I have to do alloc init for audioPlayer, which in turn resets the volume, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you use a singleton class, you can have a method to setVolume: and a variable to hold the value, let's say 0.4. inside your playNewAudio:(NSURL*) audioURL; method you can use the value of _volume to set the volume of the player after init alloc the player.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out by creating a separate variable in AppDelegate for storing the value of audioPlayer volume, and setting it back after each alloc init.